# Error submitting google assistant app

Tags: action

[Error Message: Error submitting assistant app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf5Uw.png)

I have an assistant app published and wanted to update the app. That is the reason, why I want to publish a new version of my google action. But I can't understand why I get this error message: Error submitting assistant app. Can anyone help me?

Previously, I never had any issues completing and publishing the app for production.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but after few hours it is submitted now.
Meanwhile, I made some changes in app like removed some entities with 10,000+ elements, fixed an error to make sure the app is working fine in simulator. So, not fully sure was the issue at my end or dialogflow. Can you try submitting your app now and confirm?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I fixed everything, but I can't submit the app. I have still this error message.

Comment: It's tough to comment then! Dialogflow should show the specific error but that is not the case right now. So it is a guess work. Have to check everything one by one. 
I would suggest to check and confirm everything is filled properly in "Directory Information". 
If you have modified languages then make sure all details are set for those languages.
Confirm the invocations are set properly for all languages.
Once again check and confirm the app is working fully fine in simulator.

Comment: I have replied for the same on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914611/909672 that might be useful. Is it possible for you to merge your question with that question?