# Releasing Action: "Error submitting Assistant app" with no error shown

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to publish my first Action for Google Assistent but when trying to submit the app the console tells me "error submitting assistant app" but without any details whatsoever.

Are there any logs or something which would give me more details on what I need to fix before I can submit? I'm lost. Thanks

Comment: Hi, am having the same issue today, still not working with publishing a new version of an existing app. Perhaps an internal server error from Google's side...

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. I've tried again, but still fails. Were you able to submit your app in the meantime?

Comment: Hi, I'm also having same issue now.

Comment: works for me now (without me doing any changes), the fault was on Google's side this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is being faced by many and it's really off putting to find that Dialogflow shows an error but doesn't specify details of the error which leaves developers scratching their head cluelessly. Hope Dialogflow will make this error more informative and make our lives easy.

Even I faced this error couple of times and here are some suggestions to fix this issue:

1. Make sure all the information is filled up properly under Directory Information section.

   - Long, Short Description
   - Invocations
   - Banner Image, Logo Image
   - Contact Detail
   - Privacy Policy (Terms of Service is optional so can be kept blank)

[image]

2. Under Overview menu there are tabs like

   - Quick Setup
   - Build your actions
   - Get Ready for deployment

Make sure all are showing Blue tick mark.

[image]

3. Check that you have setup the invocations properly.
4. Test your app in simulator to make sure that the app is working fine without any error.
5. Test your app in the device (you can do it with the device where you are logged in with gmail id associated with dialogflow).
6. **This one I found to be most important:**

Go to Dialogflow Consoloe and click on Gear button. Then open Environments tab and click on "View All Versions".

[image]

Here you will find the list of all the drafts of your application. It might show "Deploying" for the latest draft.

[image]

I have found that until there was a status of "Deploying", the app wasn't submitted for review. It showed "Error Submitting Assistant App" message only.

[image]

Once it was deployed, I could successfully submit the app. So, you have to wait till Dialogflow deploys your app.

Hope this will help!

Comment: There is no Environments tab there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write up. My skill went through with no problems today, so Google really did have some issues yesterday but your answer might certainly be helpful for other people!

Comment: @MaxTommyMitschke Possible. When I encountered this first time, I waited for a night and next morning, it was accepted without any change. Even I thought that Google had some issue the previous day 

Comment: @TusharSoni do you have admin level access for the app?

Comment: Oh ok, then I am not fully sure what could be the reason of Environments tab not showing there. Will update you if I find anything.

Comment: If you can't find "ENVIRONMENT" then click on 'general' -> ' enable beta features and apis'  after you will see environment tab.

Answer (score 0):

First try to identify that you have filled out the entire list of requirements for uploading an app. Usually the errors are in the Directory Information part.
[image]

Try to check that you have all the complete information here.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you fill out all information in all selected languages. In my case, I chose Japanese and English, but I did not fill out English information so the error kept coming out.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the "error submitting assistant app" ,and then click on inspect element->console and look for errors .If you get errors like 404 error connecting with server wait for one day its google's internal error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a 500 error from Google Server (see developer console)

So, I went into Dialog Flow > Gear Icon (Top Left) > General > Enable beta features and APIs.

Then the Environments tab will appear. Go to Environments and click "Publish a Version". Follow the prompts, and it will be published.